# Having a dash if field values are null

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on an angular application. I have following code in my html

```
      <div>{{ data.date | date:'d-MMM-y' || '-' }}</div>
       <div>{{ data.id  || '-' }}</div>
```

The problem I am facing is, whenever for any field like date and id, if value coming from API is null then next div shifts upward. I want div to be in that particular place it is when value is not null. So, I want to have a dash "-" whenever a value coming from API is null. So in my code I added a  `|| '-'`  to all the fields but still it is not working. I am not getting "-" in my html. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to the result, you are just missing some parentheses:

```
<div>{{ (data?.date) ? (data.date | date:'d-MMM-y') : '-' }}</div>
```

Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vb4peg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Just comment the line `this.data["date"] = new Date();` and you will see how it changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use on this case the [nullish coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operator

it will be like:

```
  <div> {{ (data.date | date:'d-MMM-y') ?? '-' }} </div>
  <div> {{ data.id ?? '-' }} </div>
```